# Is my luggage automatically transferred from United Airlines to LuxAir at Munich airport?

Tags: luggage, united-airlines, muc, luxair

I am traveling on United Airlines to Munich and then connecting to LuxAir. Will my checked in luggage be automatically transfered to the LuxAir flight or do I have to do it myself?

Answer (score 3):

I find this astonishing, but it seems the answer is no.

According to the computer reservation system, United Airlines has signed interline baggage agreements with the following airlines:

```
   MAY CHECK BAGGAGE TO
   AA  AB  AC  AF  AH  AI  AM  AR  AS  AV  AX  AY  AZ  A3  
   BA  BB  BE  BI  BR  BT  BW  CI  CM  CO  CS  CX  CZ  DL  
   EI  EK  EN  EQ  ET  EV  EY  FB  FI  FJ  FM  FV  FZ  GA  
   GF  GK  G3  HA  HO  HP  HU  HX  H2  IB  JJ  JL  JO  JP  
   JQ  J2  KA  KC  KE  KL  KM  KQ  KS  KU  KX  LA  LH  LO  
   LP  LR  LW  LX  LY  MD  ME  MF  MH  MI  MK  MQ  MS  MU  
   MX  NH  NU  NX  NZ  OA  OK  OM  OO  OS  OU  OV  OZ  PG  
   PK  PR  PS  PX  PZ  QF  QR  RJ  RO  SA  SK  SN  SQ  SU  
   SV  SZ  S2  S7  TA  TG  TK  TP  T0  UA  UL  UN  UP  US  
   UX  VA  VN  VS  VW  WM  WP  WY  XF  XL  ZH  ZK  2K  3K  
   3M  4M  4Q  4U  7H  9K  9W
```

As you will see, LG (Luxair) is *not* in the list. Therefore even on the same ticket, the baggage cannot be through-checked.

(The reason baggage interline agreements are needed is that, in international law, both the first and the final carrier in the baggage journey are both equally liable to the passenger for any defect or loss in the baggage on arrival. Therefore you may sue Luxair even though United lost the bag. Therefore how the liability is apportioned between them must be decided before the final carrier agrees potentially to take responsibility for the first carrier losing the bag.)

In the event you do manage to get this through-checked, I would be interested to hear about it!

Answer (score 2):

Single reservation? Then the airline will interline it. Two tickets? You do it (you can try to beg for checking it through, after all Lufthansa owns partially and codeshares with LuxAir so an interline agreement is likely).

Comment: I checked, and I am utterly astonished to find that LG is *not* on the UA "MAY CHECK BAGGAGE TO" interline list. (It is on the ticket issuance interline lists.) If this is right then it will simply not be possible to through-check baggage.

Answer (score 2):

You should tell the staff that you have another flight when you check in at the first airport. They may help you to transfer